# Music Player Foreground service Stops when App is removed from recent apps in Android 12

Tags: android, notifications, android-12

I am developing a simple music player using this example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svdq1BWl4r8

the  Music Player service Stops when App is removed from recent apps in Android 12

the code that I am using is

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

private void notification_manager() {
       
        playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(AudioPlayerService.this, ConstantValues.PLAYBACK_CHANNEL_ID_INT_ID,
                ConstantValues.PLAYBACK_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(mediaDescriptionAdapter)
                .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
                .setCustomActionReceiver(null).setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.app_name).setChannelImportance(NotificationUtil.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                .build();
        //Sets how PlayerNotification will Look
        playerNotificationManager.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseFastForwardAction(false);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseRewindAction(false);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseRewindActionInCompactView(false);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseChronometer(false);
        playerNotificationManager.setUsePlayPauseActions(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setUseStopAction(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setColorized(true);
        playerNotificationManager.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_LARGE);
       
    }

@Nullable
            @Override
            public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AudioPlayerService.this, MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.S){
                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AudioPlayerService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            }else {
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AudioPlayerService.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            }
            return pendingIntent;
        }
```

When we remove app from recent apps it stops on Android 11 and higher, but works fine on lower  versions

`gradle`

```
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.musicplayer"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start your service like this

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();   
 Intent intent = new Intent(...); 
context.startForegroundService(intent);
```

Start your notification with foreground

```
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```